# IOS: Code Signing Error

Tags: ios, signing

There is a lot of stuff on code signing error.. But nothing works.. I upgraded the iPod software to IOS 8 and it doesn't work in the developer mode anymore. I can run the app but I cannot debug it. Any help will be of great help. Hard deadlines to meet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should check your the provisioning profile on iTunes developer account.
Check if its valid or not. If its expired , renew it and download it.
Also check whether your iPod is added to that provisioning profile or not.
If its not added then add the device first to your profile and then download & install it.
Sign your application with this profile and try installing the app on your iPod . It should work.